# Regex match character at end of string unless multiple instances

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got an array that has `U.S.` and `banana.` as entries.

I am trying to figure out how to write a regular expression that only matches the period when it is at the end of the string UNLESS the string contains more than one period.

To illustrate: `.` in `banana.` should be a match; `.` in `U.S.` should not match because it contains more than one despite being at the end of the string.

This should work: `/(?!\..+)\.$/`. It matches the period (`\.`) and the end of the string (`$`), preceded by a negative lookahead that says: a period, followed by one or more characters `(?!\..+)`. It matches the last period in both strings.

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Is this one word at a time? If so, @elclanrs answer is perfect.

Comment: @Sam It is one word at a time. But @elclanrs answer matches `banana.` entirely, I'd only like the period

Comment: I think the reason your regex doesn't work is that the negative lookahead does just that: it looks ahead, not behind. Unfortunately the negative lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[^\.]*\.$/
```

This matches the whole word in case it has only . in the end. You can get a sub match on the . by putting it in parenthesis:

```
/^[^\.]*(\.)$/
```

Comment: I totally forgot about submatches! Thanks!